# Mapbox GL JS Cluster Realtime

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm not the best at javascript, but i want to "realtime" or any 5 seconds. update my mapbox clusters/points. Which i pull from a php-file, which "echos" geojson. It's then shown on the map but if i want to update them currently i'll have to refresh the site. I really spent hours now with combining code examples from Mapbox without luck yet this is the code i'm working with:

```
map.on('load', () => {
  // Add a new source from our GeoJSON data and
  // set the 'cluster' option to true. GL-JS will
  // add the point_count property to your source data.
  map.addSource('scooters', {
  type: 'geojson',
  // Point to GeoJSON data. This example visualizes all M1.0+ scooters
 
  data: 'mapvehicles.php',
  cluster: true,
  clusterMaxZoom: 14, // Max zoom to cluster points on
  clusterRadius: 50 // Radius of each cluster when clustering points (defaults to 50)
  });
  
  
  
  map.addLayer({
  id: 'clusters',
  type: 'circle',
  source: 'scooters',
  filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
  paint: {
  'circle-color': [
  'step',
  ['get', 'point_count'],
  '#5CB66E',
  100,
  '#5CB66E',
  750,
  '#5CB66E'
  ],
  'circle-radius': [
  'step',
  ['get', 'point_count'],
  20,
  100,
  30,
  750,
  40
  ]
  }
  });
   
  map.addLayer({
  id: 'cluster-count',
  type: 'symbol',
  source: 'scooters',
  filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
  layout: {
  'text-field': '{point_count_abbreviated}',
  'text-font': ['DIN Offc Pro Medium', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
  'text-size': 12
  }
  });
   
  map.addLayer({
  id: 'unclustered-point',
  type: 'circle',
  source: 'scooters',
  filter: ['!', ['has', 'point_count']],
  paint: {
  'circle-color': '#5F36B2',
  'circle-radius': 5,
  'circle-stroke-width': 2,
  'circle-stroke-color': '#fff'
  }
  });
   
 
  map.on('click', 'clusters', (e) => {
  const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
  layers: ['clusters']
  });
  const clusterId = features[0].properties.cluster_id;
  map.getSource('scooters').getClusterExpansionZoom(
  clusterId,
  (err, zoom) => {
  if (err) return;
   
  map.easeTo({
  center: features[0].geometry.coordinates,
  zoom: zoom
  });
  }
  );
  });
   
  map.on('click', 'unclustered-point', (e) => {
  const coordinates = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates.slice();
  const vehid = e.features[0].properties.id;
   
 
  while (Math.abs(e.lngLat.lng - coordinates[0]) > 180) {
  coordinates[0] += e.lngLat.lng > coordinates[0] ? 360 : -360;
  }
   
  new mapboxgl.Popup()
  .setLngLat(coordinates)
  .setHTML(
  `ID: ${vehid}`
  )
  .addTo(map);
  });
   
  map.on('mouseenter', 'clusters', () => {
  map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
  });
  map.on('mouseleave', 'clusters', () => {
  map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
  });
  });
```

Comment: You need to break down your problem more into the specific thing you're trying to do, and how it's failing. Don't just dump all your code and hope for the best.

Answer (score 0):

As Steve couldn't help you... i'll help you if you update like this it will update this clusters too.

```
 var url = 'mapvehicles.php';
    map.addControl(geolocate);
    map.on('load', function () {
    geolocate.trigger();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    window.setInterval(function () {
    // make a GET request to parse the GeoJSON at the url
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.onload = function () {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
    // retrieve the JSON from the response
    var json = JSON.parse(this.response);
     
    // update the scooters symbol's location on the map
    map.getSource('scooters').setData(json);
     
    
    }
    };
    request.send();
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).